# Are there any decent Websocket C# implementations?

Tags: c#, websocket

I have already created my server in `System.Net.WebSockets` and now after transferring it between machines I had noticed Windows Server 2008 is not supported, are there any other implemetations which support an X509Certificate as authentication and would require minimal conversation.

I have been googling for this in the past 2 hours but haven't found anything meaningful, just a collection of poorly written, poorly documented libraries that throw exceptions on the regular, specifically SuperSocket, the server implementation of which seems to be complete buggy bull.

Could anyone post some sample client code from a decent library? I am growing desperate.

Comment: Maybe http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/

Comment: Wow thanks for the so much informative and documented library

Comment: Hello. As Phil and Peter says you have a few options. If you want websockets SignalR does fit your demands since you need .NET 4.5 and IIS8...

Think that the XSockets, SuperWebsocket, Fleck etc will give you what you need. I´m one of the creators of XSockets. So if you head that way I (we) will help you with any questions you might have.

Good luck.

Answer (score 16):

Frameworks include:

- [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)
- XSockets
- [Super WebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/)
- [Alchemy WebSockets](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets)
- [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck)

More options available via the [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I want to ask what do you think about Akka.Net implementation (it is Actor model implementation and Whatsapp use it as I know) for Websockets? or do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: WebSocketRPC (http://websocket-rpc.net) should be also on the list.

Answer (score 6):

There is also:

- https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp - sharp implements RFC6455 and is very popular amongst Unity3d developers
- https://github.com/StackExchange/NetGain/ - stackoverflow's implementation of RFC6455

Answer (score 4):

I know it is a little bit late, but I created a [WebSocket C# implementation](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/) and it may be interesting for somebody.

Comment: Why using away method instead of event mechanism?

Comment: It allows you to approach your code in the way you prefer. For example, you can create an event based wrapper: https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/WebSocket-Event-Listener

Answer (score 1):

SignalR provides you a great way to add real-time features to your application. Under the hood, it uses either Web Sockets, Server-sent events, Long Polling or Forever Frames based on what the client and the server support. The coming version, scheduled to be released in the coming weeks, will support client-side (X509Certificate) certificates. You can refer to the following links for more details:

http://www.asp.net/signalr

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki

Comment: But...you need windows 8 or IIS to test...the windows 8 requirement is artificial IMHO and a bummer as I can't locally.